# Adding TextView(s) via java android but inserting blank views

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

With help of a suggestion from another answer I wrote the below code. But for some odd reason, it displays the text for the first TextView just fine and then, every other TextView below it is a blank! I tried many different ways but unable to figure it out. Someone please assist me..THANKS!

**JAVA code**(MainActivity.java)

```
ToDoListDB info = new ToDoListDB(MainActivity.this);
                    info.open();
                    String data = info.getData();
                    info.close();

//Split the List item string into individual strings
   String delims = "[\\n]+";
   String[] tokens = data.split(delims);

   List<TextView> itemList = new ArrayList<TextView>(tokens.length);

   for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
{
       TextView tvItem = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
   tvItem.setText(tokens[i]);                           
       tvItem.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));

       LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       itemList.add(tvItem);
   myLayout.addView(itemList.get(i));

   //myLayout.addView(tvItem);
   //itemList.add(tvItem);
}
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#DDD"
    android:hint="Enter a list item"
    android:textColor="#D00" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemListLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)   findViewById(R.id.itemListLayout);

Comment: Every textview is filling up the parent so better add android:orientation="vertical" to your linearLayout.

Comment: Yup! You are right! buptcoder posted the same thing below and it solved it! I will never forget this as I feel so stupid! Thanks!:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the layout_orientation in your linearlayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemListLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000">
```

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! My gosh, I spent last 1hr on this and for some reason didn't figure that out! And funny thing, at one point before I wrote the java code, I had a orientation in there! :D Just vote up this answer, I can't being a new user